# How to pause and resume a Thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans

I am creating a program which turns on my laptop camera, this program handles threads in Java, I am trying to pause a thread to allow another thread to execute using a toggleButton, but I see that the methods of **suspend ()** and **resume ()** are obscure, I would like to know how I could handle these threads.

**This is my class that creates the first thread and allows me to activate the camera on my laptop**

```
class Video extends Thread {

    boolean Running = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (this.Running) {
            Image image = webcam.getImage();
            jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(30);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(WebCam.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public void kill() {
        this.Running = false;
    }
}
```

**This is my other class, the one that allows you to change the color of the image, what I'm looking for is to be able to pause thread1 that runs the Video class and start thread 2 which runs the VideoGray class**

```
class VideoGray extends Thread {

    boolean Running = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (this.Running) {
            BufferedImage src = webcam.getImage();
            ColorConvertOp op
                    = new ColorConvertOp(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null);
            BufferedImage dest = op.filter(src, null);

            jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(dest));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(WebCam.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public void kill() {
        this.Running = false;
    }
}
```

**This is what I have in my ToggleButton, the vd variable belongs to the class created before Video and the vdg variable belongs to the VideoGray class created at the beginning of the main class, the vd variable is set to run at the beginning of the class main so that when you run the program it starts, so when I select the button I want to pause that vd thread and make the vdg thread run.**

```
private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    System.out.println(jToggleButton1.isSelected());

    if (jToggleButton1.isSelected()) {
            vd.suspend();
            vdg.resume();
    }



}
```

Comment: You could add another `boolean` perhaps call it `isPaused`. Add a method to toggle this `boolean` like `setPaused(boolean value)`. Inside the `while` check for `if(this.isPaused)` then do `Thread.sleep(...)` followed by `continue`.

Comment: you say so?

if(isPaused){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(30);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(WebCam.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    return;
                }continue;

Answer (score 0):

In your threads:

```
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(WebCam.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    return; // This terminates thread execution.
}
```

In your toggle button action:

```
vd.interrupt();
vdg.start();
```

Nice tutorial on this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca, I try to do it but when the toggleButton is true it interrupts the vdg thread and starts the vdg thread, now when the false toggleButton wants the vdg thread to pause and the vd thread to resume

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic example using code similar to yours:

First, a class that creates 2 additional threads, pauses and resumes them:

```
public class PauseThreadMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Runner r = new Runner();
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start(); //first runner active

        Runner r2 = new Runner();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);

        Thread.sleep(1250);
        r.togglePause(); //first runner paused
        t2.start(); //second runner active

        Thread.sleep(1250);
        r2.togglePause(); //second runner paused, first runner also paused
        Thread.sleep(1250);
        r.togglePause(); //first runner active

        //After some time stop both threads.
        Thread.sleep(1250);
        t.interrupt();
        t2.interrupt();

    }

}
```

Now the `Runner` class that performs the work:

```
public class Runner implements Runnable{
    boolean running = false, paused = false;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        running = true;

        while (this.running) {
            if(paused){
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is paused");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(250);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                }
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is doing some work");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void kill() {
        this.running = false;
    }

    public void togglePause(){
        paused = !paused;
    }
}
```

Here is some sample output:

```
Thread-0 is doing some work
Thread-0 is doing some work
Thread-1 is doing some work
Thread-0 is paused
Thread-1 is doing some work
Thread-0 is paused
Thread-0 is paused
Thread-0 is paused
Thread-0 is paused
Thread-1 is paused
Thread-0 is paused
Thread-1 is paused
Thread-0 is paused
Thread-1 is paused
Thread-0 is doing some work
Thread-1 is paused
Thread-1 is paused
Thread-1 is paused
Thread-1 is paused
Thread-0 is doing some work
```

Lastly, please note that this approach does not guarantee any happens-before relationship. It's possible that even after you call `togglePause` the thread could continue to execute for a while because it checks the `paused` variable periodically - if it has already checked this flag it won't check it again for another 250ms in my example.

You can read the [Java Tutorial on Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) for more details.

Comment: @DB  I do this

**Class video extends Thread**

 I don't know that do the class Runneable

Comment: @DB 
and I tried like you told me and it doesn't do that

Comment: The truth is I am close to completing the program but the only thing that costs me is to exchange the threads at the right time, I am new to this page, I do not know how I could make you look at all my code, could you help me, I have been looking for several days information and I can not find anything related.